# V-tiger, j-Query,Js : How to Set / Put variable (array) value in to array of input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, vtigercrm

This time i am trying to put array values coming from **for loop** inside **if condition** in to input fields . 
Here in variable **v** (where  **-:** alert(v);) value is coming like

(1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,1.00,1.00) and outside **for loop** value is (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0).
Up to this point all good,

Now i want to put this value (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) in variable v in place of (1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,1.00,1.00).

**code** edit.js :

```
getAccountName : function(container){
    return jQuery('input[name="projecttaskhours"]',container).val();
},

getDuration : function(container){
    var a = [];
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_977"]',container).val());
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_979"]',container).val());
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_981"]',container).val());
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_983"]',container).val());
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_985"]',container).val());
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_997"]',container).val());
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_999"]',container).val());
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_1001"]',container).val());
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_1003"]',container).val());
    a.push(jQuery('input[name="cf_1005"]',container).val());
    return a;

},

checktaskhour : function(form){ //alert("dsfd");
    var thisInstance = this;
    var v = thisInstance.getDuration(form);  alert(v);
    var choose = jQuery('select[name="assigned_user_id"]').prop('selected',true).trigger('chosen:updated').val(); // alert(choose).val();
    var accountName = thisInstance.getAccountName(form);
    if(choose==true){
        var multiplier = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            v[i] *= multiplier;
        }   // alert(v);

    }
},
```

That is all, please guide me if getting my point.....Thanks!!

Comment: you want to fill the array element with `0` ? then use another for loop..

Comment: yes i want that . But How to set those elements , may i use j-Query or anything else ?

Comment: simple for loop will be fine .

Comment: ok , i am trying .....................Thanks for reply